# "make" not looking for files in /usr/local/

Tags: make, gcc, cmake, solus

I'm trying to build a package from source (ROCm) (Distro:Solus): `libnuma` isn't available so I had to build it from source. And once I installed it, even though the files are in `/usr/local`, `make` still gives the error `numa.h not found`. How to add `/usr/local/include` and libraries to the path of gcc headers?

Comment: Add `-I /usr/local/include` to `CFLAGS`. You probably also need `-L /usr/local/lib` (or similar) to `LDFLAGS`. For most libraries, `pkg-config --cflags --libs` should show all the needed flags for the compiler and the linker, respectively.

Comment: That did solve the header issue, but now `ld` fails to find `-lnuma`. I did add `-L/usr/local/lib` which includes the `libnuma*`files to `LDFLAGS`.

Comment: @user414777 It seems `ld` isn't using `LDFLAGS` for some reason. Adding `-L/usr/local/lib` to `LDFLAGS` gives the error, but manually using `ld -L/usr/local/lib -lnuma` gives me the correct result. I've removed everything from `LDFLAGS` except `-L/usr/local/lib` and it still gives the same error.

Comment: That Makefile is probably using `CFLAGS` for the loading phase too (Nowadays nobody calls `ld` directly, but via the `cc` or `gcc` driver program). Try adding the `-L ..` to `CFLAGS`, it certainly won't hurt (it will at most issue a warning).

Comment: @user414777 Same issue. Because `ld -L/usr/local/lib -lnuma` doesn't give the error while `ld -lnuma` does makes me think it's an issue with `LDFLAGS`. Because `-L/usr/local/lib` is present in it. (In fact it's the only thing in it now)

Comment: @user414777 Reinstalling `ld` fixed the issues. But now I'm wondering why does anaconda ship an entire subsystem and overriding system apps.